# Python print -> Perl STDIN line skip problem

Tags: python, perl, pipe

Im newbie of perl and python.

I need to file handling in python(dataframe), and that file need to calculated in Perl.

At first, I tried to use python subprocess, and it was not working(borken pipe)

i need to multiple lines from python, and perl code need to read it and processing.

I just use | in command line, and it was work, but perl skip odds number line and just read even number line.

how can i fix it?

my python code is :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('./data.txt', sep = '\t', header = None)

datalist = list(data[0] + '_' + data[1])

for line in kinase_list:

    print(line)
```

and my perl code is :
//

```
use strict;

my %new_list = ();

while (<STDIN>){
  my $line = <STDIN>;
#  print STDERR $line;
#  chomp $line;
  my ($name, $title) = split('_', <STDIN>);
  $new_list{$title} = $name;
  print STDERR $name, "\t", $title, "\n";
}

print STDERR scalar(keys %new_list);
```

my python output 657 lines, but perl just out 329.

how can i fix it?

Comment: why do you need python for this? it seems you just need the first two columns, why not use `perl` directly, calling the two columns from the file directly?? ie `perl -pe "s/((.*?\t)(?2)).*/$1/" C:\users\file1.txt`

Comment: also `my ($name, $title) = split '_'` is enough

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I need to edit 2 dataframe and need to merge it by specific id and adjust some values two dataframe.

Comment: which should call the other? Should python call perl or should perl call python?? I don't know which is which, but you can use `import os;print(os.popen(the_code_above).read())` which should also work

Comment: python print the lines, and perl need to read and make them hash

Comment: But you can do that directly in python!! hash in perl is known as dictionaries in python

Comment: just do `hash = dict(zip(data[1],data[0]))`.  and you can obtain the elements you need for example `hash['the_title_you_want']`

Comment: I need to stdout all text.. not just value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `<STDIN>` reads a line from standard input, so your Perl code reads two lines for every iteration of the `while` loop.

It is sufficient to say

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    my $line = $_;
    ...
```

or just

```
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply! 
I just edit my code what you suggest, and successfully get all lines.
Thanks!